# Extracting Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, web-scraping

I am using scraping a webpage which renders markers on the google map. I have used NReco.PhantomJS to get the source code of the webpage including the data loaded through Ajax. I have now all the webpage source stored in a string object. Now the part I want to extract from whole source is a javascript Array declaration and initialization. It look like this,

```
var customM = [41400, 610420, 313270, 312216, 51516];
```

Now I know that I can use the StartIndex and EndIndex and get the part that I want as a SubString but there is already another similar line on the page which is commented out but extracted instead of my actual desired line,

```
// var customM = [43100, 310220, 311240];
```

Is there any other way to extract what I want? Some library or Regex for this?

Comment: Yes, you could use a regex that checks to ensure `var` is at the start of the line without the comments, something like `^var customM...`.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Of course, that would trivially be tricked by leading spaces or block comments or...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed - but it would still match what the OP has right now and be better than the substring method (which presumably is matching the first instance it finds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex like this:

```
(?:^|\n)\s*var customM = \[.*
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/cI5iC5/2)

Comment: Many thanks. It did exactly what I wanted. Without this help I would have spent hours figuring this out.